# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is unstable on my system

Tags: drivers, 12.04, nvidia, display

I have installed 12.04 LTS as a Upgrade and even after waiting for that seemed to be a very long time to complete, I found the system to be unstable and for apps not to work.

So I decided to format and reinstall, but then it went from bad to worse. I am using an nvidia graphics card: when downloading the drivers it would seem to take for ever or totally crash. When I finally get it installed and setup my dual screen when I go to run Display from the Ubuntu menu it comes up with an error message saying:

`Could not get screen information - RandR extension is not present`

Can some one please tell me what I can do to solve this, or should I go back to 11.10 and give it time for the OS to find its feet.

Thanks for any help

IAN

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the synaptic package manager gui and search for libXrandr. BTW, are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu? Which one you install, libXrandr.i386 or libXrandr.x86_64 is dependent upon that. Once done, you might have to reboot. Then you should be able to setup your display to handle the 2 screens.